# how to add a field on odoo report?

Tags: html, css, report, odoo, qweb

[image]I need to print a timesheet report for each employee, and I need to display the employee name at the header not on the column cells because it will be repeated in every row and I don't need that

I tried to use < t-foreach > but it displays the name to much

```html
<template id="19011.employee">
  <t t-call="web.html_container">
    <t t-call="web.external_layout">
      <div class="page">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h2> <strong>TIME SHEET</strong>
          </h2>
          <h2>
            <tr t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
              <span t-field="o.employee_id" />
            </tr>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-condensed" bgcolor="#875A7B">
          <tr>
            <th> check in</th>
            <th> check out</th>
            <th> Total</th>
          </tr>
          <tr t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <td>
              <t t-esc="o.check_in" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <t t-esc="o.check_out" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <t t-esc="o.total" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor="#875A7B">
            <td align="center"> <strong> Total Hours</strong></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <strong t-esc="sum([o.total for o in docs])" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </t>
  </t>
</template>
```

I need it to display the employee_id at the header or at the first column I the first row only without being repeated

Comment: Can you show the report action?

Comment: i'am added a screen shot

Comment: Move `<span t-field="o.employee_id" />` outside of `t-foreach`, replace `o` with the first record of `docs`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```
<template id="19011.employee">
<t t-call="web.html_container">
<t t-call="web.external_layout">
<div class="page">
    <h2> <strong>TIME SHEET</strong>
    </h2>
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <div class="text-center">

        <h2>
            <span t-field="o.employee_id" />
        </h2>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-condensed" bgcolor="#875A7B">
            <tr>
                <th> check in</th>
                <th> check out</th>
                <th> Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <t t-esc="o.check_in" />
                </td>
                <td>
                <t t-esc="o.check_out" />
                </td>
                <td>
                <t t-esc="o.total" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </t>
    <tr bgcolor="#875A7B">
        <td align="center"> <strong> Total Hours</strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <strong t-esc="sum([o.total for o])" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
    </t>
</t>
```